# Dynamically Creating LINQ Query to query XML Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML similar to below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
    <Result> 
        <Students>
            <Student>
                <Firstname Value="Max" />
                <LastName Value="Dean" />
            </Student>
            <Student>
                <Firstname Value="Driz" />
                <LastName Value="Jay" />
            </Student>
        </Students>
    </Result>
</body>
```

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to write some code to dynamically build a Linq query from something like,

```
string pathToElements = "Result.Students.Student";
var individualItems = pathToElements.Split(".");
```

to something like,

```
XElement document = XElement.Parse(xml);
var evaluatedResult = document.Elements("Result")
                .Elements("Students")
                .Elements("Student")
                .ToList();
```

basically the `individualItems` has 3 items "Result", "Students" and "Student". I'm exploring possible ways to create a dynamic query to accomplish something like,

```
document.Elements("Result")
        .Elements("Students")
        .Elements("Student")
        .ToList();
```

For n number of Items I would just need to keep appending .Elements("") to the query.
Any advice on how to achieve this, my first instinct was to use a string builder and have the query as a string. I was able to do this but was not able to find out how a LINQ query which is in the form of a string can be executed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can use XPath.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/dotnet/framework/general/query-xpathdocument-xpath-csharp

Answer (score 1):

You can query XML using XPath (it's a string so you can create it dynamically) then you can deserialize the item

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/dotnet/framework/general/query-xpathdocument-xpath-csharp

The output of this code

```
using System;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<body>
    <Result> 
        <Students>
            <Student>
                <Firstname Value=""Max"" />
                <LastName Value=""Dean"" />
            </Student>
            <Student>
                <Firstname Value=""Driz"" />
                <LastName Value=""Jay"" />
            </Student>
        </Students>
    </Result>
</body>";
        
        using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
           var xdoc = new XPathDocument(tr);
           var nav = xdoc.CreateNavigator();
           var nodeIter = nav.Select("/body/Result/Students/Student");
           while (nodeIter.MoveNext()) 
           {
                Console.WriteLine("Student: {0}", nodeIter.Current.InnerXml);
           };           
        }       
    }
}
```

is

```
Student: <Firstname Value="Max" />
<LastName Value="Dean" />
Student: <Firstname Value="Driz" />
<LastName Value="Jay" />
```

Comment: To deserialize a Student it's better to use nodeIter.Current.OuterXml